# Setting an MVC TextBox to Initial Value in Razor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.textboxfor

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC but I haven't been able to find an explanation for this.

My questions is regarding the difference in the `value` attribute in the generated HTML when I use `@HtmlTextBox()` vs. `@HtmlTextBoxFor()`.

I can set the initial value for an `<input>` using `@Html.TextBox()` like this:

```
@Html.TextBox("Phone", "Initial Value", htmlAttributes: new { id = "txt_phone" })
```

The generated HTML is just what you'd expect:

```
<input id="txt_phone" name="Phone" type="text" value="Initial Value" />
```

Please notice the generated `value` attribute above.

Using `@HtmlTextBoxFor()` is a different. Please note that I have a very simple model in my view. It has a `Phone` property which is a `String`.

Here's an attempt at setting an initial value using `@Html.TextBoxFor()`:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { id = "txt_phone", value="Initial Value" })
```

The generated HTML, however, does not reflect the `value` attribute:

```
<input id="txt_phone" name="Phone" type="text" value="" />
```

**My first question is, "why did the generated HTML not reflect the 'Initial Value' text in my `value` attribute?"**

As many of you know, the "right way" to set the initial value with `@HtmlTextBoxFor()` is like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { id = "txt_phone", Value = "Initial Value" })
```

But look at the generated HTML:

```
<input Value="Initial Value" id="txt_phone" name="Phone" type="text" value="" />
```

As you can see it generates a `Value` attribute (with a capital V) yet it still generates a `value` attribute with a lowercase v and an empty string!.

**My second question then, is, why does `@Html.TextBoxFor()` require a captial V in `Value` yet still generate a lower-case v, `value` with an empty string?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The answer to "why?" is because this is not the way you're supposed to pass a value. The HTML helpers use a bit of fairly complex logic to determine what the value of a field should be, and because it varies based on a number of different circumstances, your attempt at adding a manual value are largely ignored.

The first place Razor looks for a value is in `ModelState`, which is composed of the data from `Request`, `ViewData` and `ViewBag`. Then, it looks on the view's `Model`. Finally, it will fallback to the "default" value, which really only applies with the non-`For` helpers, where you can specify the value to default to. The reason you can't do the same with the `For` helpers is because they are bound to an actual property, and therefore, take that property's value, even if it's just the default of `null` or `0` or something.

Long and short, if you want to bind to a property *and* have it default to a specific value, then that value needs to be the default for the *property*. For example:

```
private string phone;
public string Phone
{
    get { return phone ?? "Initial Value"; }
    set { phone = value; }
}
```

Now, the property itself will always return "Initial Value" if it's previously unset, so your form field will as well.

Comment: Chris, I've not doubt you're right but some empirical evidence is not consistent with what you mentioned, or, more likely, is a result of my misunderstanding.

Let's say we have the same code you show above, along with this Razor bit:

`@Html.TextBox("Phone", null,  htmlAttributes: new { id = "txt_phone" })`

Even though I am not using the `-For()` form, I still get binding to the model. Now if I modify the Razor to this:

`@Html.TextBox("Phone", "Big Dog",  htmlAttributes: new { id = "txt_phone" })`

I override the model's default. It seems *both* forms of helpers participate in binding.

Comment: The main thing I was getting hung up on (and still am) is this weirdness where there is a capital V for value in the `-For` form of the helper. I'm not so concerned about the binding, What I was really wondering about is what appears to be the asymmetry in the use of the `value` attribute between the non-`For` form of the helper and the -`For` form.